# Embedded vimeo or youtube video needs to play directly in full screen mode by clicking a custom play button

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, youtube-api, vimeo-api

I have a requirement to play YouTube or Vimeo embedded video in fullscreen mode directly using the players' API by clicking the custom play button.

I tried this codepen method:    https://codepen.io/fregante/pen/GgOvLM

But I can't able to exit the fullscreen mode by clicking the player exit fullscreen button, in youtube its says **fullscreen not available**

I am stuck, help me!!!

```
   var requestFullScreen = iframe.requestFullScreen || iframe.mozRequestFullScreen || iframe.webkitRequestFullScreen;
  if (requestFullScreen) {
    requestFullScreen.bind(iframe)();
  }
}
```

Comment: Does the video allows fullscreen? - see [related thread](https://support.google.com/youtube/thread/1945455/full-screen-is-not-available-in-embedded-video?hl=en) - also, if I understand, you want to *(once the video is in fullscreen)*, the video *should* autoplay, right?